# The user remains in the logged state on the first device when logged in from the second device

Tags: android, authentication, interceptor

I have this Interceptor for send aut token and catch errors:

```
public class AuthHeaderInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    private final UserStorage userStorage;

    public AuthHeaderInterceptor(UserStorage userStorage) {
        this.userStorage = userStorage;
    }

    @Override
    public Response intercept(@NonNull Chain chain) throws IOException {
        String authToken = userStorage.getUserProfile().getAuthToken();
        Request request = chain.request().newBuilder().addHeader("X-Authorization", authToken).build();

        try {
            Response response = chain.proceed(request);
            if (response.code() == 401) {
                throw new IOException("Authorization token is missing");
            }
            if (response.code() == 403) {
                throw new IOException("Invalid authorization token");
            }
            return response;
        } catch (ConnectException e) {
            throw new IOException("Error connecting to server");
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
            throw new IOException("Connection timeout");
        }
    }
}
```

When user loggin from another device `authToken` change on the server and first user in loggin state. When first user try make som request or try logout - he get `403` error. I want next - when user get `403` error I want clear user data and redirect user to loggin activity. I have 2 questions:

1. How cant I redirect user to another activity(StartActivity) from `AuthHeaderInterceptor` ?
2. Is it correct at all what I want? How can this be done differently?

Answer (score 0):

Using **[RxAndroid](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid)** and retrofit can simplify this process. Use a dependency injector like [dagger](https://github.com/google/dagger) so that redirecting (mentioned as the first requirement) from [**anything**] is just abstracted out using [Inversion of Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control).

Comment: "Using RxAndroid and retrofit can simplify this process." - I use rxjava. can you explain how it will help me in this matter? And I use Dagger2 - I inject Context to AuthHeaderInterceptor but I'm not sure how right it is